# repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions is not a member of RDD[(K, V)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to do secondary sort with Scala Spark, following this [blog](http://codingjunkie.net/spark-secondary-sort/#:%7E:text=Secondary%20sorting%20is%20the%20technique,user%20logons%20to%20your%20application.). And I have the following code:

```scala
case class TokenZidKey(token: String, zid: Long)

object TokenZidKey {
    implicit def orderingByTokenZid[A <: TokenZidKey]: Ordering[A] = {
        Ordering.by(tzk => (tzk.token, tzk.zid))
    }
}

class TokenZidPartitioner(partitions: Int) extends Partitioner {
    override def numPartitions: Int = partitions;
    override def getPartition(key: Any): Int = key.asInstanceOf[TokenZidKey].token.hashCode() % numPartitions;
}

object SetSim {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        ...
        val linesWithZid = dataLines.zipWithIndex();
        def mapZidByToken(r: (String, Long)): Iterable[(TokenZidKey, String)] = {
            for (t <- r._1.split(" ")) yield (new TokenZidKey(t, r._2), r._1);
        }
        val tokensWithZid = linesWithZid.flatMap(mapZidByToken);

        val tokenZidPartitioner = new TokenZidPartitioner(tokensWithZid.context.defaultParallelism);
        val tokenZidsWithSecondarySort = tokensWithZid.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(tokenZidPartitioner).map(r => {
            (r._1.token, (r._1.zid, r._2))
        }).toDF("token", "zid_with_line");
    }
}
```

where `tokensWithZid` is `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(TokenZidKey, String)]`, but I still got

```
value repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(TokenZidKey, String)]
```

Any idea why and how I fix this? Is it that my custom `TokenZidKey` is not recognized as a proper RDD key that is sortable?

Comment: Try this format: rdd.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(2, lambda x: x % 2, True)  Not sure a case class works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the code works, the issue is I tested it in spark-shell and when input on different lines, spark-shell does not register the case class and the companion object as on the same file.

So if you want to test this in spark-shell, enter the case class and companion object in a single line like the following

```
case class TokenZidKey(token: String, zid: Long); object TokenZidKey {
    implicit def orderingByTokenZid[A <: TokenZidKey]: Ordering[A] = {
        Ordering.by(tzk => (tzk.token, tzk.zid))
    }
}
```

Comment: indeed some oddities there

Comment: you can use `:paste` in spark-shell too, and then you can keep them on separate lines.